# Android Cardview strange behavior

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

I have simple Cardview with strange behavior. 
When i run my app everything is ok - as i show on first pic.
When i scroll down, and again scrollup each Cardview element change height and looks like on pic 2. Any idea what cause this problem?
[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

And my xml:
Content Scrolling:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="flex.com.sklepik.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/main_activity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="flex.com.sklepik.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Single card:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView

        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/card_shop_radius">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"/>


        </RelativeLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: height of root view of recyclerview item, in this case `LinearLayout` should not be match_parent. set a fixed value.

Comment: yes it solve my problem. @Saurabh could you put it in answer? I will mark it. Anyway many thanks

Comment: Or instead of some hardcoded fixed value, you can set `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for LinearLayout, CardView and for RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

height of root view of recyclerview item, in this case `LinearLayout` should not be match_parent. set a fixed value.